# Как получить изображение из папки внутри проекта с помощью multipartfile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

У меня хранится изображение в папке upload внутри проекта, пытаюсь подгрузить его с браузера,либо postman - возвращает такую ошибку - не могу ничего найти по ней! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в логах спринга пишет это -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя спринг multipartfile отправляет с содержимым

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Изначально был неправильный подход - надо возвращать массив байтов вот в таком оформлении все успешно работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]